# Is there any serial communication software for VB 6.0,?

Tags: vb6

I am compiling a VB 6 code which requires serial communication from ports. For performing serial communication, I need some software tool like SAX Commstudio Active X or MSComm.ocx. But the problem is I have downloaded Sax Commstudio Active X from the commstudio official website, but that was  a trial version for 1 day only. then i tried to download the same software from 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/
But the link is unavailable.
Now I am really in a fix how to get any of the serial communication software which is compatiable with VB 6 code. It will be better if some one provide me the sax commstudio download link or nay serial communication software downalod link!

Regards
Asad

Comment: Why not use MSComm, which comes with VB6?

Comment: Dear Jay, I have complete msdn license and i have downloaded VB6 from the msdn website. It was there in .iso format in 2 CD's. After downloading when i installed VB6, it seems it installed only CD 1 and nerver ask for CD 2. I presume that may be CD 2 is not installed (which may contain MSComm)., The VB6 IDE,Compiler is working correctly. Don't know how to use MSComm with my code?

Comment: Plz guide! And tell me have i installed the VB6 correctly or there is a mistake in installation. Or I am not using the MSComm properly!

Comment: I've never installed VB6 from .iso so I can't say if your installation is OK.  It probably is if you think the compiler is working correctly.  I'm not sure how far you've gotten with the MSComm control, so I posted an answer that describes adding the control to your toolbar.  My apologies if this is not where you're stuck; if you have some code that's given you problems feel free to open a new question showing your code and ask specific questions.  I'm sure there are many in the SO community who are experts at using the control (I'm certainly not one of them).

Answer (score 3):

**Adding the VB6 MSComm Control to your Toolbar**

In the VB6 IDE, select menu item Project, then select Components.  The Components dialog box will appear.  On this dialog, in the Controls tab, check the box next to the item 'Microsoft Comm Control 6.0' and then click the OK button on the dialog.  This will add the component to your toolbar.

It's been a while since I've used this control but maybe this article will help you get started:

[Visual Basic: MSComm Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393(VS.60).aspx)

If you Google *mscomm* you'll find many more articles.

Comment: I believe you will need VB6 Pro as I heard this did not work with some versions of VB6 .. the problem was resolved by installing VB6 Professional. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add the mscomm control in the components tab : Project - Components - Microsoft Comm Control 6.0

then add the control to your form and use the following code to configure and open it :

```
with mscomm1
  .settings = "9600,N,8,1"
  .commport = 1
  .portopen = true
end with 'mscomm1
```

to send something :

```
mscomm1.output = "output to send"
```

use the oncomm event to receive data :

```
private sub mscomm1_oncomm()
  dim strinput as string
  select case mscomm1.commevent
    case comevreceive
      strinput = mscomm1.input
      processdata strinput 'process the data here
  end select
end sub
```

(code is unchecked, just typed in, but i think it should work :))